# Parse: Cannot sign up a user created automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm using Parse 1.7.1 for iOS and I am trying to sign up a user. I chose to let the user interact with the app before I force the sign up / login process. The problem is that as soon as I call signUp the session object disappears from the server and causes any subsequent calls to return error 209.

Here's some code:

### AppDelegate:

```
[PFUser enableAutomaticUser];
[[PFUser currentUser] incrementKey:@"runCount"];
[[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
```

When I check the Parse Core console I can see a valid User & Session.

### MyController:

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
if (! user) {
    user = [PFUser user];
}
user.email = @"my@email.com";
user.password = @"somepassword";
user.username = @"whatever";
// I also tried Save instead of signUpInBackground... same result
[user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded) {
        NSLog(@"Success signing up");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
```

When I check the console there is an updated user but there is no Session anymore.

### Any other API call

```
[Error]: invalid session token (Code: 209, Version: 1.7.1)
```

Despite the fact that the callback returns `success` as soon as I try to interact with the Parse API I get a 209, invalid session token. This is fair enough, since the session object is not present in the console.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Note: this a brand new app (not affected by the change made by Parse on the 25th of March)/.

Comment: Did you try to use PFAnonymousUtils logInWithBlock? instead of enableAutomaticUser

Comment: Yes, I have. Any subsequent "save" or "sign up" calls cause the server side session object to disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have raised this as a bug with Facebook and they are fixing it in 1.7.3

[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/497789333708746/)'s the conversation I had with them.

Comment: I am on 1.11.0 and as far as I can tell it is not fixed even though the linked Facebook thread says it was fixed in 1.7.3. Other people on the thread said it was not fixed also. Can anyone confirm or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Create  button with selector -signUpSelector. And need implement this code:

```
-(void)signUpSelector
  [PFUser becomeInBackground:@"session-token-here" block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
PFUser *newUser = nil;
  if (error) {
  newUser = [PFUser user];
   } else {
   newUser = user;
  }
  user.email = @"my@email.com";
  user.password = @"somepassword";
  user.username = @"whatever";

  [user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
   if (succeeded) {
    NSLog(@"Success signing up");
    }
   else {
    NSLog(@"Error %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
   }];

}];
```

Comment: I actually need to have a user available straight away when the app starts.